# PostGIS (or rpostgis) issue on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, r, ubuntu, postgis-2.2

I've installed PostgreSQL 10 and PostGIS on Ubuntu following instructions [here](https://kitcharoenp.github.io/postgresql/postgis/2018/05/28/set_up_postgreSQL_postgis.html). Now I'm migrating an R interface from Windows to said Linux box and have an inconsistency I can't sort out.

When I `pgInsert` a normal table I have no trouble: the first insert creates my table, second adds to the table, etc.

When I try to `pgInsert` a geometry object into a new table, PostGIS fails, complaining:

> Creating new table... Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn,
>   statement, ...) :    RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result :
>   ERROR:  relation "spatial_ref_sys" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT srid
>   FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE auth_name = 'EPSG' AN...

Seems there is a subsystem containing CRSs which I am missing?

Comment: did you remember to create the postgis extension in your database?

Comment: I did indeed, the postgis 2.5 extension is active and verified from r using `pgPostGIS(conn)` ... however I did not fully grok the permissions (my rpostgis user had CREATEROLE) ... changing to superuser allows me to see the EPSG tables. I need to dig a little more to understand exactly what role postgis needs to use spatial extensions.

Comment: It is common to install PostGIS in the (default)  `public` schema to avoid such problems.

Comment: Which I did @CL, the installation is basic. This problem showed up when I used my R interface to connect to postgis using another (non-superuser) role, which I understood to be best-practice.

Comment: What is the `search_path` configured for the database or the role?